# Loading activities from external dex/jar

Tags: android

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html

This link refers loading of classes from Second Dex, this is working fine

Instead of calling a simple method available in Second Dex,
I tried to add an activity in Second dex, and Tried to access from my MainActivity,
I'm getting Classnotfound error when I try to access/start the activity using startActivity() from My MainActivity

I also tried using PathClassLoader - its also showing same error

Can we access/load that Activity present in Second Dex from MainActivity?

What it the proper way to keep activities in multiple Dex file?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: did you launch it successfully? I can't find the class successfully: `05-20 17:11:10.028: E/AndroidRuntime(32561): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dex/com.example.dex.lib.LibActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.dex.lib.LibActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.dex-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.dex-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]`

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can, The only thing you need is to mention the Activity details in the **application's manifest** file.

Also make sure, the layout file for the activity is there.

Example : I'm planning to load TestActivity in a library jar file from My Application.

TestActivity.class (Resides in jar File):

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(getIntent().getIntExtra("LAYOUT", -1));
}

}
```

MainActivity.class (Resides in Application project)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);

    Intent intTest = new Intent(this, TestActivity.class);
    intTest.putExtra("LAYOUT", R.layout.activity_test);
    startActivity(intTest);
}

}
```

layouts : actitivity.xml and activity_test.xml both should reside in application's layout folder.

Need to mention TestActivity in Manifestfile.

```
<activity android:name="yourPackage.TestActivity"></activity>
```

Comment: Thanks Eldhose,  
Also make sure, the layout file for the activity is **there**.  
Can you pls tell me, what **there** refers to?

Comment: It means, the layout xml file for the activity in jar should also resides in the Application project layout folder. Will modify the answer to give an example.

Comment: Thanks Eldhose, Tried similar way earlier, TestActivity cannot be referred directly from MainActivity, as it resides in different dex file, we need to use Reflection to get TestActivity reference. Once startActivity() is executed, i am getting ClassnotFound Error

Comment: Hi Ram, why you cannot refer the TestActivity? If you need to create the instance of TestActivity using reflection you need to get its reference over there right?

Comment: When you try to call 'startActivity' to start another activity in a secondary dex, a 'ClassNotFoundException' would happen for the activity you're trying to start is not in the class path. As far as I could see, I didn't find a way to achieve this. If it is possible, please let me know. thanks